# How to convert S3ObjectInputStream to Base64 url?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, base64, bufferedimage

I have a `png` image file in an `AWS S3 bucket`. I'm trying to get this image using Java SDK. So far, here is what I have done:

```
public String encodeBase64URL(BufferedImage imgBuf) throws IOException {
    String base64;

    if (imgBuf == null) {
        base64 = null;
    } else {
        Base64 encoder = new Base64();
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        ImageIO.write(imgBuf, "PNG", out);

        byte[] bytes = out.toByteArray();
        base64 = "data:image/png;base64," + encoder.encode(bytes)
                .toString();
    }

    return base64;
}

public String saveImageToS3(BufferedImage imgBuf, String id) throws IOException {
    AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client();

    File file = File.createTempFile(id, ".png");
    file.deleteOnExit();

    ImageIO.write(imgBuf, "png", file);

    s3.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, id, file));
    file.delete();

    return bucketName;
}

public String downloadImageFromS3(String id) throws IOException {
    AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client();

    S3Object obj = s3.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, id));
    BufferedImage imgBuf = ImageIO.read(obj.getObjectContent());

    String base64 = encodeBase64URL(imgBuf);
    return base64;
}
```

The `saveImageToS3` method works exactly as expected. However, the second method returns `data:image/png;base64,[B@428d24fa` while it should have been a valid `Base64`.

What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Comment: Well, your `encodeBase64URL` method is wrong at least. You seem to be doing a `toString()` on a `byte[]` in it (that's where the `[B@428d24fa` comes from).

Comment: I included the `encodeBase64URL` method. Yes, there is a `toString()` on the `byte[]`. What do you suggest I do?

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: it worked! thank you very much! this is a stupidity that I'll never repeat!

Comment: In addition to the fix by @Kayaman, you probably want to remove the `ImageIO.read/write`s, and instead just Base64 encode the bytes from the PNG file directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of calling `toString()` on the resulting `byte[]` which will result in the very unhelpful `[B@428d24fa` format, you need to create a new `String` **using** the returned bytes:

`base64 = "data:image/png;base64," + new String(encoder.encode(bytes), "UTF-8");`

Answer (score -1):

I had some problems with **`Base64 encoder = new Base64();`**
So I resolved it by not using encoder and I have replaced "**encoder**" by **`Base64.getEncoder()`** everywhere.

**Example:-**

```
if (img == null) {

    base64 = null;

} else {

    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    ImageIO.write(img,"PNG",out);

    byte bytes[] = out.toByteArray();

    base64 = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(bytes),"UTF-8");
}
```